# Is it possible to import an entire xcode ios project to flutter

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

I have zero experience with android, and I am very new to Flutter. I want to make an android version of my ios app, and wondered if I could use Flutter with the existing xcode app to make an android version (if that makes sense)

Comment: What language did you develop your iOS app in?  If it is in Swift then you need to start again in flutter/dart

Comment: it’s completely in objective c

Comment: Then you need to start again in flutter/ dart